# Add dynamic class to "datetimepicker"

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have two fields in my page.One is `datepicker` another one is `datetimepicker`.
Both fields have same `classes` and same `id`.

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content"></div>
```

I am binding Date pickers in this way:

```
$scope.bindDate('#appliedDate');
$scope.bindDateTime('#appliedTime');
```

Now I need to add dynamic class `dtPicker` to only `bindDateTime` field.
I tried this:

```
$scope.bindDateTime = function(value) {
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass("dtPicker");
     $(value).datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(datetext){

        },
    });
  }
```

But dynamic class is added both `datePicker` and `dateTimePicker` fields.I want to add it only `dateTimePicker` field.How to do it?

Comment: Try this : `$(this).addClass("dtPicker");`

Comment: You can't have the same `id` on two different elements.

Comment: id should be unique for each elements . you should not duplicate it

Comment: @AlivetoDie which `$scope` code you are asking ?seriously I din't get you.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have only one `$scope.bindDateTime` in my code,that also I have updated here.

Comment: @krish  create a fiddle example link of your problem please

Answer (score 0):

You may use [:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) or [:last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) property along with your selection. But don't use same id for both fields. Instead of use it inside class attribute.

```
$scope.bindDateTime = function(value) {
    $('#ui-datepicker-div:first').addClass("dtPicker");

  }
```

or

```
$scope.bindDateTime = function(value) {
    $('#ui-datepicker-div:last').addClass("dtPicker");

  }
```

Here you need to check which one first occurred in the document either `datepicker` or `datetimepicker`

Comment: Share your html code for scope variables. It may help me to solve it!

Comment: @krish  please create a fiddle example link of your problem with your html and script code.We can check and let you know

Comment: Sure.You guys are spending your valuable time for me :-)thanks a lot :-)But my code is very large I am unable to attach here ,that is why I am searching some other way(trying to add class only for focused elements).If I don't get any alternative solution I will add fiddle here.Again thanks alot guys:-):-) especially @AlivetoDie thank you so much.

Comment: @krish  you can create a fiddle link by some dummy  html element (structure need to be same as you have in your html) and with your script code. May be that can help too

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3x32s66k/  check this fiddle I dont know why its not working.Here I need to add dynamic class only for `datetimepicker`.